# python split by comma only if comma has trailing character

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
with open(dict_file) as record_list:
    for x in record_list:
        dictionary_list.append([r for r in x[:-1].split(',')])
```

I'm trying to split only if a comma is between characters, for example, `"abc,abc"`, but skip split if a comma has trailing space: `"12, Main St"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex with lookbehind and lookahead for the match required:

```
import re

s = "abc,abc"
print(re.split(r'(?<!\s),(?!\s)', s))

# ['abc', 'abc']
```

Comment: I tried it before, didn't work, and now it did :D  -  Thank you